# meaning of kannel status

Tags: status, smpp, kannel

we have configured kannel, and the status look like

```
SMS: received 0 (0 queued), sent 15133 (0 queued), store size 0
SMS: inbound (0.00,0.00,0.00) msg/sec, outbound (3.08,15.23,0.02) msg/sec

DLR: received 14232, sent 0
DLR: inbound (11.45,5.64,0.02) msg/sec, outbound (0.00,0.00,0.00) msg/sec
DLR: 980 queued, using internal storage

Box connections:
    smsbox:vsmsc, IP 127.0.0.1 (0 queued), (on-line 8d 21h 38m 41s) 

smsc1[smsc1]    SMPP:xxxxx.xxxxx.com:2775/2775:xxxxx:SMPP (online 769120s, rcvd: sms 0 (0.00,0.00,0.00) / dlr 1 (0.00,0.00,0.00), sent: sms 1 (0.00,0.00,0.00) / dlr 0 (0.00,0.00,0.00), failed 0, queued 0 msgs)
```

in the DLR inbound, it showing (11.45,5.64,0.02) msg/sec. There is 3 value inside (). What is the meaning of each?

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Average for the last minute;
2. Average for the last 5 minutes;
3. Average for all of runtime.